# Connected components of bipartite graphs

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory, bipartite, connected-components

I'd like to extract connected components (as bipartite graphs) from a bipartite graph using `networkx`. But connected components in `networkx` is not for bipartite graphs but general undirected and direct graphs. Is there an example of bipartite graphs? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by connected components of a bipartite graph, if they're not the connected components of the underlying undirected graph?

Comment: They are. But the components need to be represented as bipartite graphs. I don't think the connected components general graphs will automatically do so.

Comment: Could you post your full testing code as an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subgraphs corresponding to connected components of a bipartite graphs (and indeed any graph) themselves carry over all node attributes, so that in particular, you can use those to mark your partitions, as in [the docs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/bipartite.html):

```
In [28]: B = nx.Graph()
    ...: B.add_nodes_from([1, 2, 3, 4], bipartite=0)
    ...: B.add_nodes_from(['a', 'b', 'c'], bipartite=1)
    ...: B.add_edges_from([(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'c')])
    ...:
    ...: G = B.subgraph(next(nx.connected_components(B)))

In [30]: G.nodes
Out[30]: NodeView((1, 2, 'a', 'b'))

In [31]: G.nodes[1]
Out[31]: {'bipartite': 0}
```

Comment: How to get the nodes from bipartite 0 and 1. `  for g in nx.connected_components(B):
    print([x for x in g if B.nodes(data=True)[x]['bipartite'] == 0]) 
    print([x for x in g if B.nodes(data=True)[x]['bipartite'] == 1]) ` I use something like this. I am not sure if this is the most efficient way.

Comment: This is cleaner:  `B.nodes[x]['bipartite']` rather than `B.nodes(data=True)[x]['bipartite']`.  I'm not sure whether it's more efficient, since I'm not sure how `B.nodes(data=True)` is implemented, but it might be quite a bit faster.  It's definitely not slower.

Comment: My guess would be that the moment you're setting up the bipartite graph in the first case, you'll have some way of indexing the partitions, so you never even have to look up the attributes.